# Scientific image processing - minimal bounding area for selection (imageJ?)

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

what is the best way to find minimal bounding area around some (point) selection?
Convex hull doesn't fit my reqirements completely, here's an image explaining what I want:
[image]

Further more, I'm looking for a java solution to this problem, preferably some imagej procedure (I'm guessing this is basic stuff for you image processing gurus out there). 
Of course, I'd appreciate any other suggestion too, or a generic algorithm.

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: This is way late, but you certainly don't want the minimum area either. The minimum area would look like a skeleton. What you want is Alpha-Hull.

Answer (score 2):

You might make some progress with a [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).  But have a look at other answers here on SO on the topic of [*concave hull*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1200).

`ImageJ` is a closed book to me, I can't help in that direction.